# Visual Studio's Test Explorer breaks when trying to link object files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I want to use Visual Studio's Test Explorer to run my Google Tests. When I create a console project and add a default Google Test project, and build the solution, it finds the tests as intended.

[image: Default tests running]

Now I want to create my own class, where everything is set up in the header file.

```
class foo
{
    public:
        foo() : the_count(0) {}
        ~foo() = default;

        void count_plus() { the_count++; };
        int get_count() { return the_count; };

    private:
        int the_count;
};
```

Then I modify my `test.cpp` file (the default file created by Visual Studio's Google Test project) to make use of my new class.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "..\ConsoleApplication2\foo.h"

class tester : public testing::Test {

    public:
        foo bar;

        void SetUpTestSuite() {
            std::cout << "Setup..\n";
        }

        void TearDownTestSuite() {
            std::cout << "Teardown..\n";
        }
};

TEST_F(tester, TestFixture1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(bar.get_count(), 0);

    bar.count_plus();

    EXPECT_EQ(bar.get_count(), 1);
}
```

Building this solution also automatically detects the tests and runs them succesfully.

[image: Still working...]

Now it gets interesting... When I move my implementation of `foo` to a `.cpp` file.

foo.h

```
class foo
{
    public:
        foo();
        ~foo() = default;

        void count_plus();
        int get_count();

    private:
        int the_count;
};
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

foo::foo()
{
    the_count = 0;
}

void
foo::count_plus()
{
    the_count++;
}

int
foo::get_count()
{
    return the_count;
}
```

And then I build the solution, I initially get a linker error complaining about unresolved externals.

[image: Unresolved externals]

However, if I change the test project's linker settings to point to the other project like so:

```
Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> add $(SolutionDir)ConsoleApplication2\$(IntDir)*.obj
```

which I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722333/linker-error-while-unit-testing-with-visual-studio-c) answer, I can succesfully build the project.

However, after I finish building the project, I'm no longer able to see or run my tests.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is Visual Studio just broken?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The project which generates the object files cannot have a `main()` function, as this overrides Google Test's `main()` function.

I solved it by:

1. Creating an *empty* project (with no `main()`) which contains all my source code and set this project's **Configuration Type** as **Static library (.lib)**.
2. Creating a console application project (or whatever suits your needs) which contains my `main()` entry point. In this project, I add a reference to my `.lib` project.
3. Create a Google Test project. In this project, I also add a reference to my `.lib` project.
4. Set the project in step two as the **Startup project**.

Now when you want to run your code, it will run it from your one entry point, but grab the source from `.lib` project and your Google Test project will also grab this `.lib` file, detecting all your tests.